# How to add close button on pdf opened in new window

Tags: html, web-applications

In a web app I want to open pdf saved in the same folder in HTML5.

The aim has been accomplished. But now I want to add a close button to the PDF opened. So, as to return to the original page .

I am not getting any way to do the same. Kindly suggest.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please add the code you use.